# running low voltage wire from outside to inside

Tags: wiring

I have low voltage wire under my deck.  I would like to drill a small hole (1/4 in or less) and feed the cable through the deck ledger board and the house's rim joist so that I can keep the transformer inside (the basement which is unfinished).  I would then fill the hole with silicon to keep water and bugs out.

Is this an absurd idea?  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd seal around the cable with [duct seal](http://www.idealindustries.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=duct-seal&div=5&l1=accessories), instead of silicone.

[image: Duct Seal]

It stays pliable, and will not interact with the cable jacket.

Comment: as the NEC master, are you aware of any code sections that govern this application?

Comment: There is something called "duct seal" that looks exactly like this but appears to be for sealing seams in HVAC sheet metal ducts and is marked "not for outdoor use".  Presumably this is not the same compound you're recommending.   Do you know?